# run model for each line of model parameters (meta) data.frame

Tags: r, purrr, modelr

In the spirit of purr, broom, modelr, I am trying to create a "meta" data.frame in which each row denotes the dataset (d) and the model parameters (yvar, xvars, FEvars). For instance:

```
iris2 <- iris %>% mutate(Sepal.Length=Sepal.Length^2)
meta <- data.frame(n=1:4,
           yvar = c('Sepal.Length','Sepal.Length','Sepal.Length','Sepal.Length'),
           xvars= I(list(c('Sepal.Width'),
                         c('Sepal.Width','Petal.Length'),
                         c('Sepal.Width'),
                         c('Sepal.Width','Petal.Length'))),
           data= I(list(iris,iris,iris2,iris2)) )
```

Now, I would like to run a model for each column of "meta". And then add a list column "model" with the model output object. To run the model I use an auxiliary function that uses a dataset, a y variable and a vector of x variables:

```
OLS_help <- function(d,y,xvars){
  paste(y, paste(xvars, collapse=" + "), sep=" ~ ") %>% as.formula %>% 
    lm(d)
}
y <- 'Sepal.Length'
xvars <- c('Sepal.Width','Petal.Length')
OLS_help(iris,y,xvars)
```

How can I execute `OLS_help` for all the rows of meta and adding the output of OLS_help as a list column in `meta`? I tryed the following code, but it did not work:

```
meta %>% mutate(model = map2(d,yvar,xvars,OLS_help) )
Error: Can't convert a `AsIs` object to function
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace
```

OBS: The solution to when only the "data" (nested) list column ([corvered in Hadley's book here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html)) is:

```
by_country <- gapminder %>% group_by(country, continent) %>% nest()
country_model <- function(df) {  lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = df) }
by_country <- by_country %>% mutate(model = map(data, country_model))
```

Comment: Why work within the `tidyverse` but use a `data.table`? I recommend sticking to one ecosystem. Furthermore, I'm unclear about what you're trying to do. You mention a model but I don't see any code pertaining to fitting any form of model to your data. Is `meta` your input data? If so, can you provide your expected output based on your sample data. That will help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your sample code is not reproducible; it produces an error "[...]  object 'iv' not found". It sounds to me you're after `map2` or `pmap`. Happy to show an example if you update your input data.

Comment: I edited the question, trying to add reproducible example as I could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pmap` in the following way

```
df <- meta %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(fit = pmap(
        list(yvar, xvars, data),
        function(y, x, df) lm(reformulate(x, response = y), data = df)))
## A tibble: 4 x 5
#      n yvar         xvars     data               fit
#  <int> <chr>        <I<list>> <I<list>>          <list>
#1     1 Sepal.Length <chr [1]> <df[,5] [150 × 5]> <lm>
#2     2 Sepal.Length <chr [2]> <df[,5] [150 × 5]> <lm>
#3     3 Sepal.Length <chr [1]> <df[,5] [150 × 5]> <lm>
#4     4 Sepal.Length <chr [2]> <df[,5] [150 × 5]> <lm>
```

Explanation: `pmap` iterates over multiple arguments simultaneously (similar to base R's `Map`); here we simultaneously loop throw entries in column `yvar`, `xvar` and `data`, then use `reformulate` to construct the formula to be used within `lm`. We store the `lm` fit object in column `fit`.

Comment: nice, tks! Could you clarify the role of `mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)` in your solution?

Comment: @LucasMation `reformulate` requires input objects to be `character` vectors/scalars; since in your `meta` data `yvar` is a `factor` we need to convert the column to a `character` vector. That's what the `mutate_if` call does (it actually converts *all* `factor` columns to `character` columns). A canonical `tidyverse` approach uses `character` vectors whenever possible (to be precise, in the `tidyverse` implicit `character` to `factor` conversions are avoided, since many problems stem from such conversions that happen e.g. in base R's `data.frame`, `read.table` etc.).

Comment: I still get errors if I try to predefine the function before with `OLSa <- function(y, x, df){ lm(reformulate(x, response = y), data = df) }`  and then run `... mutate(fit = pmap(list(yvar, xvars, data),OLSa(y,x,df)))`

Comment: @LucasMation I cannot reproduce; defining the function outside doesn't make a difference. The following still works: `f <- function(y, x, df) lm(reformulate(x, response = y), data = df); meta %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% mutate(fit = pmap(list(yvar, xvars, data), f))`. So the error must lie elsewhere with your code and/or data.

Comment: Ah I see the issue. You're using `pmap` incorrectly. It should be `... mutate(fit = pmap(list(yvar, xvars, data), OLSa)`.